# How do i add a variable that changes value into different sections of a list? (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x

I'm not sure if this has been asked but i was having trouble with some code for a project i'm doing in class. So for this part i need to make a function that takes in a variable (y) and adds it to a specific spot in a list [0,0,0,0,0] -> [y,0,0,0,0]. Then +1 to the variable and placing it in the next spot [y,y+1,0,0,0].

[This is what i have currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7mJt.png)

Comment: Please remove the image link and post the code correctly formatted here.

Answer (score 0):

There's not much reason to start with the list being full if you're going to just overwrite the contents, so the simplest code would probably be:

```py
year_list = []
for year in range(y, y + 5):
    year_list.append(year)
```

You could also just take the range and turn it into a list:

`year_list = list(range(y, y + 5))`

Comment: I see, I'm rather new with python but would "for year in range(y, y + 5):" this bit of code make a list of 5 or would i need to put the values in individually?

Comment: The code in the loop will run five times, with a different value of `year` each time.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you need to insert the value at a particular position, below is the code for that.

```
y_pos = 0  # enter the actual position of y-1 here. 0 means it will 
           # inserted at the beginning, 1 means inserted at 2nd 
           # position

year_list = []

# this intialises the list upto y_pos + 5
for i in range(y_pos+5):
    year_list.append(0)

for i in range (y_pos,y_pos+5):
    year_list[i] = y + (i - y_pos)
```